# Find the mode of a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dictionary={}
list=[1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
maximum=0
for values in list:
   if values in dictionary:
      dictionary[values]+=1
   else:
      dictionary[values]=1
if not maximum or dictionary[values]>maximum[0]:
maximum=(values,dictionary[values])
mode=maximum[0]
print("Mode:",mode)
```

Output:3

The output should be 1 and 3 since both occur twice.

Comment: `collections.Counter([1,1,2,3,3,4,5])`

Answer (score 3):

You are basically reinventing the built-in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
In [3]: my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

In [4]: from collections import Counter

In [5]: counter = Counter(my_list)

In [6]: max_count = max(counter.values())

In [7]: mode = [k for k,v in counter.items() if v == max_count]

In [8]: mode
Out[8]: [1, 3]
```

Edit:

python 3 does support [statistics.mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode); however, an error is raised on your list, since no unique mode exists.

Comment: This comment saved me. Thanks for especially pointing out that statistics.mode throws an error when no unique mode exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) to get `mode`

```
>>> from scipy.stats import mode

>>> mode(alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Function to return all modes, this function takes into account multimodal distributions.
# Function returns all modes as list or 'NA' if such value doesn't exist.
def mode(l):
    if len(l) > 1: #
        #Creates dictionary of values in l and their count
        d = {}
        for value in l:
            if value not in d:
                d[value] = 1
            else:
                d[value] += 1

        if len(d) == 1:
            return [value]
        else:
            # Finds most common value
            i = 0
            for value in d:
                if i < d[value]:
                    i = d[value]

            # All values with greatest number of occurrences can be a mode if:
            # other values with less number of occurrences exist
            modes = []
            counter = 0
            for value in d:
                if d[value] == i:
                    mode = (value, i)
                    modes.append(mode)
                    counter += mode[1] # Create the counter that sums the number of most common occurrences

            # Example [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
            # 2 appears twice, 3 appears twice, [2, 3] are a mode
            # because sum of counter for them: 2+2 != 5
            if counter != len(l):
                return [mode[0] for mode in modes]
            else:
                return 'NA'
    else:
        return l

l1 = [1]
l2 = [1, 1]
l3 = [1, 1, 2, 2]
l4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l5 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
l6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
l7 = ['string', 'string', 1]
l8 = ['string', 'string', 1, 1, 1]

print mode(l1)
print mode(l2)
print mode(l3)
print mode(l4)
print mode(l5)
print mode(l6)
print mode(l7)
print mode(l8)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Another way of finding mode

```
def mode(lst):
    d = {}
    for a in lst:
        if not a in d:
            d[a]=1
        else:
            d[a]+=1
    return [k for k,v in d.items() if v==max(d.values())]
```

Comment: Please describe your code when providing an answer with a few comments.